# How to Access the data in Span element using Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am new to Robot Framework. I am trying to access the element/link inside a span tag. The number is a quote ID, which is a hyperlink that redirects to another page. Should I use Click Element or Click Link?

[image]

```
<div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">
<span>563929450915</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `click element` and `click link` to see what would happen?

Comment: Yes i have tried but didn't work.Is there any other way to perform this action as element data is in span tag.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that this link is really a javascript event method with a underscore styling through CSS. This makes it appear to be a link, and more importantly behave like one. However, it may not work when we apply `Click Link` keyword on it.

As the event can be set to any tag, please use `Click Element` on the `<span>` but if that does not have the desired effect, on it's parent tags `<div>` and `<td>`. Any further up the tree doesn't make sense.